# Jekyll/Liquid way to print numbers with separator character?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am printing large numbers in Jekyll (powered by Liquid), which by default does not perform any sort of formatting. I'd like to print integers with separator characters, e.g. render `12000` as `12,000`.

I've looked for a filtering option in Liquid that supports this to no avail. Do I need to write my own extension/filter and do this myself?

Comment: There is a way of doing that with javascript, documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat). Apparently, there's no default filter to doing that from Liquid itself, but you can try adding a [custom filter](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/567). There are some [money filters](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/money-filters) which can be useful if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like there is a built-in filter to do this, and as "Virtua Creative" mentioned in a comment Shopify provides a JavaScript library for doing locale-specific number formatting. (Which makes sense, since the Jekyll code is generated with zero context of the environment where it will be read.)

So creating a plug-in is your best bet. However, it appears that a plug-in already exists to do this (and other basic types of filtering). See:

https://github.com/23maverick23/jekyll-humanize